# Image does not appear after calling it from API - ReactJS Hook

Tags: reactjs, image, api, react-hooks

I'm having difficulty in displaying a image that I had retrieve from calling my API. In the web console, it did show my image string but however, the image did not show up in my web application. A small white box with a cross appear instead of the actual image. Am I calling the image wrong in the html portion ?

Code: Calling API to retrieve image

```
const [getText, setText] = useState([])
const [getImg, setImg] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const url = "API link"

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json[0]["results");
            console.log(json[1]["image");
            setText(json.[0]["results"]);
            setImg(json.[1]["image"]);
        }catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

return (
       .
       .
       .
       <img src={getImg}></img>
)
```

Comment: where `img` tag to show the image?

Comment: my bad, edited the source code.

Comment: you need to change it to getImg

Comment: yes, I change it to getImg but the image still wasn't able to appear

Comment: You still have not closed the parenthesis in the setText and setImg! In the lines where you setText do this `ssetText(json.[0]["results"]);` and `setImg(json.[1]["image"]);` You are MISSING the LAST ) in each line

Comment: nope, the image still has not displayed. The image exists on my server, earlier you asked about the file path is "./media/output_images/heatmap_result.png"

Comment: does the image load if you enter it in the browser with the full url like `http://www.xinxlaxserver.com/media/output_images/heatmap_result.png`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are a few typos or either you just mistakenly didn't catch them. I've fixed them and commented the changes based on your original code you shared. It would help if you could provide what your img api returns, hopefully this works for you.

```
const [getText, setText] = useState([])
const [getImg, setImg] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const url = "API link"

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json[0]["results");
            console.log(json[1]["image");
            //getText(json.[0]["results"]; // Did you mean 'setText' instead? also closing ')' parenthesis missing
            setText(json.[0]["results"]);
            //getImg(json.[1]["image"]; // Did you mean 'setImg' instead? also closing ')' parenthesis missing again
            setImg(json.[1]["image"]);
        }catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);

return (
       .
       .
       .
       <img src={getImg}></img>
) // Did you mean to use getImg in the return JSX, because setImg would make no sense since it is a function to set the image
```

the `useState()` React hook returns `[value, updatingFunction] = useState(<initialValue>)`. The value can be used in the JSX but if you want to change the value then you use the updating function which begins a re-rendering cycle.

Comment: If this worked for you please mark it as correct, or comment and let me know if it didn't. I'll update my answer and try to find a fix for you. The code you shared originally was missing closing parenthesis ')' and was treating getText and getImg as a function, so I answered based on those fixes

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I tried editing according to yours in my web application but the issue stays the same. I forgot to include the img tag at the bottom, but the image still did not appear.

Comment: did you change it to getImg?

Comment: My API img return the img filepath.

Comment: yes I change it to <img src={getImg}></img>